# $L\cap\left(M+\left(L\cap N\right)\right)=\left(L\cap M\right)+\left(L\cap N\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to prove

> $$L\cap\left(M+\left(L\cap N\right)\right)=\left(L\cap
>  M\right)+\left(L\cap N\right)$$

RHS is in LHS: it's easy to see that each of intersection of RHS is in LHS. How to make sure that the whole sum is in RHS?

LHS is in RHS: I've no idea how to tackle this.

Comment: Something in the lhs is in L and has the form $m+l$ for $m \in M$ and $l \in L\cap N$. If you could only show $m \in L\cap M$ you'd be done...

Answer (score 0):

The whole point to me is basically in showing that the $L\cap$ - inside the bracket on the LHS is redundant, i.e. to show that $L\cap (M+L\cap N)=L\cap(M+N)$. In one direction this is obvious, since $M+L\cap N$ is a subspace of $M+N$. In the other direction what you do have is that if $m+n\in L$ then either both $m,n\in L$ or both $m,n\not\in L$ (otherwise you will have the sum of two elements in $L$ which is not in $L$).